# How to configure pem file for nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I've got 3 files:

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

and also a keystore. How can I create a .pem file out of these? I was trying to put its content to a file called .pem, but nginx says

> SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate
>   routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Also those file haven't got any attributes. Only `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` , key and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a certificate for your domain. After you get it, concatenate all those files together. This is your file to be used in nginx configuration.

```
cat yourdomain.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > bundle.crt
```

Also don't forget to configure path to private key. It is a different file.

Comment: what is yourdomain.crt?

Comment: The certificate file for your domain. You should have received it from your CA. It has the same structure as the other crt files.

Comment: File you want to use in your nginx configuration.

Comment: Have you configured path to private key? It is a different file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69388/discussion-between-zakjan-and-tony).